# I want to store data in 2 dimensional array

Tags: python-2.7

I want to store data in 2-dimensional arrays, data are coming from txt files and store in array as of now it store in 1-d array, I want to store all values in 2-d array.

```
class expample():
    def __init__(self):
        self.lin  = [[],[]]
        self.lout = []
    def gen_in(self):
        lin_files =  ['textfile0.txt','textfile1.txt', 'textfile2.txt', 'textfile3.txt', 'textfile4.txt', 'textfile5.txt',
                        'textfile6.txt', 'textfile7.txt', 'textfile8.txt', 'textfile9.txt', 'textfile10.txt', 'textfile11.txt']


for antenna_num in lin_files:

        self.in_file = open( antenna_num,'r').readlines()
        self.lin = [ int(i) for i in self.in_file ]
        print(self.lin)
```

Comment: Could you give an example of  your files and the expected output?

Comment: @palvarez all files contain 32 values like [111111...111]. and i am able to print [111..11] [111...] ....[1111..11] but i want all data will store in 2-d arrays like [[11..11],[111..11],[],....[111..11]].
please give some clue regarding 2d array, where i have to change or add something. 

Thanks

Comment: Your code is missing too much stuff. The only thing I could tell is to create a list and `append` all the lists you already have.